# Software Installation Center Not Available

Tags: 17.04

Greetings For A Good Day , 
I am a new user to UBUNTU and finding it very good to use on my laptop.
While exploring , I am not sure what I did but i kind of lost the software center application and not sure how to find it. 
Please can some one help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from 17.04, Ubuntu no longer include "Software Center" in it's repositories, i.e. you will not find "Software Center" in a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04.

There are many alternatives available, for example:

- Synaptic Package Manager
- Ubuntu Software
- Debian Package Search

You can install them by using the terminal:

1. Open the terminal by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+T`.
2. In the terminal type:

   - `sudo apt-get install synaptic` if you want Synaptic Package Manager;
   - `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software` if you want Ubuntu Software; or
   - `sudo apt-get install packagesearch` if you want Debian Package Search.

You can also install packages directly through `apt-get` if you know exactly the package names of the packages you want to install.

Hope you have a great time using Ubuntu.